# Step-Child Dependency for Non-US Citizen

Tags: united-states, taxes

For long term expats living in another country with a step-family / step-children via marriage.

Looking at [[26 U.S. Code § 152 - Dependent defined](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/152) as a reference which states:

> The term “dependent” does not include an individual who is not a citizen or national of the United States unless such individual is a resident of the United States or a country contiguous to the United States.

With a caveat subtitled "Exception for adopted child." but text of -

> Subparagraph (A) shall not exclude any child of a taxpayer (within the meaning of subsection (f)(1)(B)) from the definition of “dependent” if—
>
> (i) for the taxable year of the taxpayer, the child has the same principal place of abode as the taxpayer and is a member of the taxpayer’s household, and
>
> (ii) the taxpayer is a citizen or national of the United States.

which would sort of imply that a step-child should be qualified as a dependent. Even if they can't get an ITIN number. Does this seem a reasonable interpretation of the law? If so, how do people take this up with the IRS so they can claim non-US-citizen-step-children as dependents?

Comment: The section talks about adopted children, not step-children. Unless you adopted your step-child, your step-child is not your adopted child.

Comment: Thank you. I agree the label is misleading - I'm voting with the text which specifies any child of a taxpayer. If they had intended it to mean "adopted" - the text should be consistent. Let's see what they say in 15 business days or less.

Comment: No, it clearly says child "within the meaning of subsection (f)(1)(B)", which defines adopted child.

Comment: they called back - if you want to add an answer, the reputation points are yours. I'll send a note to my congressman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section you mentioned is for adopted children of US nationals only. The section's title says "adopted child":

> **(B) Exception for adopted child** Subparagraph (A) shall not exclude any child of a taxpayer (within the meaning of subsection (f)(1)(B))
>   from the definition of “dependent” if—
>
> (i) for the taxable year of the taxpayer, the child has the same
>   principal place of abode as the taxpayer and is a member of the
>   taxpayer’s household, and
>
> (ii) the taxpayer is a citizen or national of the United States.

and the text says "any child of a taxpayer (within the meaning of subsection (f)(1)(B))" which refers to the following part that defines it as only for adopted children.

> **(B) Adopted child**
>
> In determining whether any of the relationships specified in
>   subparagraph (A)(i) or paragraph (4) exists, a legally adopted
>   individual of the taxpayer, or an individual who is lawfully placed
>   with the taxpayer for legal adoption by the taxpayer, shall be treated
>   as a child of such individual by blood.

You have not mentioned that you have adopted your step-children. If you haven't adopted them, then the exception wouldn't apply to them.

Answer (score 1):

Same section, subsection (f)(1):

> (1) Child defined
>
> (A) In generalThe term “child” means an individual
>   who is—
>
> (i) a son, daughter, stepson, or stepdaughter of the taxpayer,
>   or
>
> (ii) an eligible foster child of the taxpayer.

You need SSN to get certain things (like child credit etc), and you can ask for ITIN if needed instead.

Comment: Thank you. I just want the dependent exemption - nothing fancy.  A previous application for an ITIN for a stepchild was rejected as he was not a "Qualifying Child" .Specifically - 'If your adopted child applies ITIN , he must be a U.S.citizen,U.S.national or U.S.resident to be considered a "qualifying child ". The definition of "Qualifying child" is vague,but IRS will not overturn this result unfortunately.'

Comment: @NJL this is weird. I guess you can point them to the actual law? If a child is a US citizen/national - the child gets SSN. And child, specifically, doesn't need to satisfy residency requirements.

Comment: It's a child who is not a US citizen (sadly other issues prevent that without moving to the US - which we are planning on). That child does meet the stepson clause and the exception to the "non-nationals" clause so I think I have a case here... will report back after revisiting this. thank you!

Comment: They'll get back to me in 2-weeks to see if they can provide any revised guidance on why the case would have been rejected... apriori it should have gone through.